# Redirect domain to specific URL on other domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, typo3

I have got apache2 server with one virtual host. It is typo3 CMS. There are multiple pages:

```
foo.com -- DNS A record --> 32.32.32.32
  |_ foo.com/bar/
  |_ foo.com/baz/
```

Now I want to configure other domain (qux.com, also with A record to IP same as below) to redirect it to foo.com/baz/, for example when user put qux.com in browser I want him to see qux.com in address bar and foo.com/baz/ webpage. In order to do this I have put this configuration to file in sites-enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qux.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://foo.com/baz/ [P]
```

but it has no effect. What is a cause? How to configure it properly?

Edit: here is my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName foo.com
        ServerAlias *.foo.com
        ServerAlias qux.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qux.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*) http://foo.com/baz/ [P]
        DocumentRoot /var/builds/stage
        <Directory /var/builds/stage>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to add another VirtualHost?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName qux.com
        ServerAlias *.qux.com
        Redirect / http://foo.com/baz/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It is works, but i don't want users see the target URL.

Comment: With RewriteRule you'll end up redirecting the user to another domain anyway. Still, another VirtualHost is the correct solution. Just replace Redirect directive with `DocumentRoot /var/builds/stage/baz/`

You really should read [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) examples first – it's all thoroughly explained there with all the suitable examples.